# $state.go in Ionic with ion-nav-view does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have started an Ionic Tabs project. Now I have a button "initiateProcess" that I call with `ng-click` and within the controller it performs some operations and then finishes it with going to a certain state (`tab.target`) with `state.go` or `state.transitionTo`.

However, when I don't include that state in my tabs.html, the state will not be loaded. When I do include it, then state.go works fine. This state is independent (can be seen as a child state but not per se) and I don't want it to show in my tabs.

What is going on?

**tabs.html (without the `tab.target`)**

```
<!--
Create tabs with an icon and label, using the tabs-positive style.
Each tab's child <ion-nav-view> directive will have its own
navigation history that also transitions its views in and out.
-->
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">


  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios7-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios7-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  // when I include here Target Tab with <ion-nav-view name = "tab.target" ... then it works


  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios7-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios7-gear" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

**app.js**

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ionic.utils', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.controllers-cloaking', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.target', {
    url: '/target',
    views: {
      'tab-target': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-target.html',
        controller: 'TargetCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

**function in DashController (`$state` has been injected)**

```
 $scope.initiateProcess = function() {

        // some stuff

        $state.go('tab.target')

    }
```

**button in tab-dash.html**

```
<button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="initiateProcess()">
     Go to Target
    </button>
```

Comment: Can you check your console to see if it throws any errors or warnings?

Comment: No errors or warnings....

Comment: check your errors. Usually there is one list that list your filename, and its error. You can ignore the default ionic errors like this :(http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7888:12).

Comment: I don't see any errors. The thing is that it works as long as I include in my tabs.html the ion-nav-view name="tab.target"

Comment: well, tabs in ionic needs name. it matches the name of views in your app.js...  .let me put in proper format

Answer (score 1):

check if your router really work by disabling the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise() . Because it will automatically route you back to tab.dash, which seems like the router is error. 
 
if your url does change to tabs/target/, which mean your router indeed work correctly. try this.

```
   <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios7-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios7-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/target">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-target"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

.state('tab.target', {
    url: '/target',
   'tab-target': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-target.html',
      controller: 'TargetCtrl'
    }
  })
```

ion-nav-view is like UIViewController in ios. it is container for your view. If you decide to name it, then you must match the name of views in $stateProvider. Basically ionic is confused where do you want to show tabs.target, because there is no matching container

Comment: How do you redirect to the state tab.target from the controller?

Comment: Try to check if your router really work. Disable $urlRouterProvider( by commenting it), and then check your url while clicking. does your url change to "/tab/target"? If it does, then the problem is with the nav-view

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem, I was trying to go to a view which didn't have a tab, just like you.

The solution is easy:

When you define your target state, the one that does not have a tab:

```
.state('tab.target', {
    url: '/target',
    views: {
       'tab-target': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-target.html',
        controller: 'TargetCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

Simply set the value of "views" like another state that have a tab, such as:

```
.state('tab.target', {
    url: '/target',
    views: {
       'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-target.html',
        controller: 'TargetCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

Then, when the user browes to the target tab, in the tab bar the "dash" tab will be the one displayed as actual tab.